# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, discord

I am a beginner discord bot maker and use python (so sorry if I don't understand anything). I have seen a lot of threads and websites for fixing this problem but I can't understand it and have been having this problem for a few months then I decided to post here.

**Code:**

```
@client.command()
async def work(ctx):
    global profit, chance, money, percent
    f= open(str(ctx.message.author.id)+".txt","a+")
    f.close
    f= open(str(ctx.message.author.id)+".txt","r")
    f.seek(0)
    money = str(f.read())
    money = int(money)
    f.close
    #f = open("using.txt", "a+")
    #f.write(",work  -  " + str(ctx.message.author) + "  -  " + str(ctx.message.author.id) + "\n")
    #f.close
    await ctx.send("Working")
    percent = random.randint(1, 100)
    profit = int(money) + int(percent)
    f= open(str(ctx.message.author.id)+".txt","a+")
    f.write(str(profit))
    f.close
```

**Details:**
I am trying to make a feature of my discord bot where it saves money for each player with a txt file when they use *,work*. When they work again, the bot reads the txt file and adds the money from the txt file to their profit, then writes it back down.

The error that I keep on getting is:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Please respond if you know a way to fix this problem and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the input when the program fails? It seems that it can't be converted into `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you need to answer yourself is what happens when you read an empty file - there will not be any information parsable as an integer (your code would try to do `int('')`, which is impossible)! You could solve it by adding some error checks:

```py
money = int(money) if money else 0
```

Apart from that, I would recommend looking through python's `with` statement to handle file operations, it will help you avoid errors such as missing brackets around function calls (`f.close` should've been `f.close()` in your case). See the example linked [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Finally, I would recommend getting an editor which highlights issues as you write code - for example [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). You can also [join Python's discord](https://discord.com/invite/python) and nicely ask people when having problems.